# How to run SQL *Loader on Mac?

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I installed the new Oracle client software package on my Mac by following instructions, but when i attempt to run the .bat file in the Terminal, I get the following error:

`-bash: sqlloader: command not found`

(I copy and pasted the contents of the .bat file into the terminal, was this incorrect?)

1. How do I run .bat files properly?
2. Is there a different, Mac-specific command for SQL *Loader?

Comment: What exactly did you install, and what did you run - .bat files are a Windows thing, not Mac. Have you set up the environment properly?

Comment: you want this https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html - pick the one that says "Tools Package - Includes Data Pump, SQL*Loader and Workload Replay Client"

Comment: I'm still confused about the `.bat` part, but if you're talking about the latest 18.1 instant client (as Jeff linked to) you've unzipped both the basic[lite] and tools packages, and cd'd into the `instantclient_18_1` directory, then just doing `./sqlldr` should work and give you the usage info as a starting point. Note that it's `sqlldr` not `sqlloader`...